# Change Progress Bar Xamarin Android (C#)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I try to make custom Progress Bar for my Splash screen.

I make it like this.

Here is ProgressBarStyle.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rotate xmlns:android =" http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%" android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="360">

  <shape android:shape="ring" android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
         android:thicknessRatio="8" android:useLevel="false">

    <size android:width="76dip"  android:height="76dip"/>


    <gradient android:type="sweep" android:useLevel="false"
              android:startColor="#F57847"
              android:endColor="#E67E55"
              android:angle="0"/>
  </shape>
</rotate>
```

And here is my `.axml` file code:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/logo_320"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="318.1dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="117.1dp" />
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="67.4dp"

        android:background="@drawable/ProgressBarStyle"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="127.4dp" />
    <TextView
        android:text="ЗАГРУЗКА КЭША "
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="52.0dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="28.0dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:paddingLeft="95dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My problem is that Progress Bar didn't change it is still default.

Where is my problem?

Comment: I also have this problem. and it seems that the progress bar UI wont change unless the process leaves the scope where it was changed. I suggest using another thread, I have not tried that myself and I am still looking for a better solution.

Comment: It looks like the progress bar support has been slowly improving over time. For me personally I was able to do almost everything in shared code except the heightRequest didn't work for Android. I was able to use the ScaleY property in my xaml to work around it.